# Create a QObject in another thread and retrieve it to the current thread = ASSERT failure in Debug on msvc16

Tags: qt, qthread, qobject

I am just trying to set a parent on a QObject created in another thread (the object is of course moved to the parent thread before), that's all !

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

class Thread : public QThread //Just a convenient Class using a lambda
{
public:
    Thread::Thread(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QThread(parent){}
    std::function<void()> todo;
protected:
    virtual void run() override{
        todo();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Change this flag to switch behaviours
    bool tryToSetParentInThread = true;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    QObject mainObj;
    QObject *dummy; //Just to get back obj created in thread;

    Thread thread;
    thread.todo = [&](){
        //QObject *obj = new QObject(&mainObj); //"QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread." ! Of course!

        // So we try this
        QObject *obj = new QObject;
        dummy = obj;

        qDebug()<<obj->thread();
        obj->moveToThread(mainObj.thread());
        qDebug()<<obj->thread(); //Check that the Thread affinity change is done

        if(tryToSetParentInThread)
            obj->setParent(&mainObj);

        QObject::connect(obj, &QObject::destroyed, [](){ //Parent mecanism is OK
            qDebug()<<"Child destroyed";
        });
    };
    thread.start();
    thread.wait();

    if(!tryToSetParentInThread)
        dummy->setParent(&mainObj);

    return 0; //No need for an event loop here
}
```

Edit :
Maybe the call of `obj->setParent(&mainObj)` doesn't like that mainObj is not in the thread calling the method ..?

This example is working fine in release, but if you try to launch this code in debug with mscv16:

[image]

Comment: From [`QObject::moveToThread()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) docs: "The object cannot be moved if it has a parent.". Perhaps this also applies to this case.

Comment: @VladimirBershov Yes but when I'm doing a moveToThread() obj doesn't have parent yet

Comment: `QObject::moveToThread` only schedules the move.  When it returns the thread affinity of the `QObject` has not changed.

Comment: @G.M. `QObject::moveToThread` seems to be 
synchronous. No mention in documentation of just a sheduling...
I have updated my example to check this. When `QObject::moveToThread` returns, the thread affinity seems to be effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I debugged qt lib, the problem comes from setParent() doing a `sendEvent()` without checking the thread affinity. The 2 objects lives in the same thread but the setParent() called is done from another one. Even though my operation isn't typical, it's still valid.. It's a simple bug or at least an unhandled case.

Depending on the calling thread it should do a `postevent()` instead.

[image]

Finally I've just replaced `obj->setParent(&mainObj)` by

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&mainObj, [&mainObj, obj](){
 obj->setParent(&mainObj);
});
```

This call is automatically done with a Queued connection and finally executed in the correct thread. Of course we have to start the eventloop in the main thread to retrieve this queued event.

This is an acceptable workaround

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>

class Thread : public QThread //Just a convenient Class using a lambda
{
public:
    Thread::Thread(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QThread(parent){}
    std::function<void()> todo;
protected:
    virtual void run() override{
        todo();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QObject mainObj;

    Thread thread;
    thread.todo = [&](){
        //QObject *obj = new QObject(&mainObj); //"QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread." ! Of course!

        // So we try this
        QObject *obj = new QObject;

        qDebug()<<obj->thread();
        obj->moveToThread(mainObj.thread());
        qDebug()<<obj->thread(); //Check that the Thread affinity change is done

        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&mainObj, [&mainObj, obj](){
            obj->setParent(&mainObj);
        });

        QObject::connect(obj, &QObject::destroyed, [](){ //Parent mecanism is OK
            qDebug()<<"Child destroyed";
        });
    };
    thread.start();
    thread.wait();

    QTimer::singleShot(0,[](){
        qApp->quit();
    });
    return a.exec(); //Add an event loop for the connect (queued) from the thread -> setParent() triggers a SendEvent() in the main thread where the two object now live
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> Even though my operation isn't typical, it's still valid.. It's a
> simple bug or at least an unhandled case.

Plain bullshit.

There is no bug in Qt, the bug is in your code.
obj is being instantiated from the Thread::run thread (ie, your lambda).
Then you move it out of THIS thread (the Thread::run thread), then you can no longer directly communicate with it, because thread safety...
QObject is reentrant, not thread safe.
The only way to continue to communicate with this pointer is via synchronization, ie using queued events / connections like QMetaObject::invokeMethod, QTimer::singleShot or emitting a signal connected to obj slots.

> This is an acceptable workaround

No. It is the only way to correctly do things.

Comment: No need to be aggressive ! 
"you can no longer directly communicate with it" :-D. I think you misunderstood the meaning of "thread safe". It on only means that you can use an object in different threads without handling synchronization...  I can call any method on a QObject in another thread if I handle synchronization (via Mutex for instance). No need here to do it because `mainObj` and `obj` are not used in the main thread and the event loop starts only after the end of the other thread. You